# IIS Compression and HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: ssl, https, iis-6

Does IIS Compression (IIS 6.0) work with SSL?  I haven't been able to find any definitive articles on the subject.  If it does, are there any additional set up instructions that need to be taken besides what Microsoft has explained on [TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx?mfr=true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Compression is applied first and then encryption (SSL).

Our site uses IIS 6 compression and SSL:

https://www.httpwatch.com/

Nothing special has to be done. SSL and compression are separately configured.